# Mapping Minipar dependencies to Stanford Parser dependencies

Tags: computational-linguistics, parsing, dependency-grammar

I am trying to use the algorithm in Qiu et al., 2011, ["Opinion Word Expansion and Target Extraction through Double Propagation"](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1162/coli_a_00034) for my research. However, in the paper, they use Minipar for dependency parsing and I would prefer to use Stanford Parser.
I found the description of the dependencies [from Minipar](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch18.html#sec:parsers:minipar:GR) but I find them very vague. For Stanford Parser, I am referring to [the list here](http://universaldependencies.org/en/dep/index.html).

Since I am not a linguist, I am having trouble finding the mapping myself. The list of the dependencies that I need to map and my best guesses for the matching dependencies is the following:

- mod: probably amod, also nummod?
- pnmod: possibly nmod, also nmod:npmod? nmod:poss? nmod:tmod?
- subj: probably nsubj, could also include nsubjpass, csubj and csubjpass
- s: no idea
- obj: probably dobj
- obj2: iobj?
- desc: Not even mentioned in the GATE list

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the paper ["Improving Opinion Aspect Extraction Using Semantic Similarity and Aspect Associations"](http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI16/paper/view/11973/12051), Liu et al., 2016, where the authors use the algorithm by Qiu but with Stanford Dependencies, i.e., exactly how I want to do it. They use the dependencies *amod*, *prep*, *nsubj*, *csubj*, *xsubj*, *dobj* and *iobj* (and *conj*). I don't know the exact mapping (if it even exists) but it isn't important for my work.